# Invalid Date giving in safari While parsing Date mith milliseconds

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I'm trying to parse `new Date("2021/09/21 18:59:00.000000")` but getting **`invalid Date`**
The problem occurred in safari and working fine in chrome.
Any Solution?

Comment: why did you use the PHP tag?

Comment: Bcz Date is coming froom php server

Comment: You might try `let [Y,M,D,H,m,s,mu] = "2021/09/21 18:59:00.000000".split(/\D/); console.log(new Date(Y, M-1, D, H, m, s, mu.slice(0,3)));`.

Answer (score -4):

Just use:

```
new Date("2021/09/21 18:59:00")
```

and then add milliseconds.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).